# Injecting a variable definition into F# quotation

Tags: f#, quotations

I have a custom variable definition, that I want to insert into a quotation. Is it even possible with the quotations syntax sugar?

What I wanted to do:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
let var = Var("myvar", typeof<int>)
let op = <@@ fun l -> match l with
        | [] -> 0
        | %%myvar :: _ -> ... @@>
```

I've also tried `<@@ let %%myvar = ... @@>` with a similar purpose.

In both cases I got FS0010 "Unexpected prefix operator in binding", or "... in pattern matching".

Is there a way to inject an existing Var like this? Or do I have to resort to manually generating the entire expression?

PS: I am using the whole thing to translate some other AST into an F# quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe in your question is really kind of nonsensical. You cannot splice a [`Var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/quotations.var-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) into an expression. Only a value of type `Expr` can be spliced. If you created an instance of `Expr` our of your `var` via the [`Expr.Var` constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/expr.var-method-%5bfsharp%5d), then the splicing would be possible:

```
let var = Expr.Var( Var("myvar", typeof<int>) )
let op = <@@ fun l -> %%var @@>
```

But this won't let you do what you're trying to do: you can't splice an expression in a pattern position (the left side of an arrow `->` inside a `match` is what we call a "pattern", and so is the left side of equal sign `=` inside a `let`). You can only splice expressions, not other parts of the syntax. F# code quotations are not quite as free-for-all as Lisp macros or TemplateHaskell.

Admittedly, it is not entirely clear what you're actually trying to do.

---

One possibility of your true intent that comes to mind is this: you want to match this variable on the left side of the arrow `->`, then pass it to some other function which would construct the right side of the arrow `->`. Something like this:

```
let mkRightSide var = <@@ %%var + 42 @@>

let var = Expr.Var( Var("myvar", typeof<int>) )
let op = <@@ fun l -> match l with
             | [] -> 0
             | %%var :: _ -> %%(mkRightSide var)   // Doesn't compile
         @@>
```

Which would yield the following quotation:

```
fun l -> match l with
| [] -> 0
| myvar :: _ -> myvar + 42
```

If this is your intent, then I suggest having `mkRightSide` return a function, which would simply take `myvar` as a parameter:

```
let mkRightSide = <@@ fun myvar -> myvar + 42 @@>

let op = <@@ fun l -> match l with
             | [] -> 0
             | (myvar:int) :: _ -> (%%mkRightSide) myvar @@>
```

The above would yield the following quotation:

```
fun l -> match l with
| [] -> 0
| myvar :: _ -> (fun myvar -> myvar + 42) myvar
```

*Note 1:* the type annotation on `myvar` is necessary because your quotations are untyped. Since `mkRigthSide` carries no type information, the compiler can't infer `myvar` to be `int` and makes it generic instead, which causes type mismatch when the splicing is attempted.

*Note 2:* the parentheses around `(%%mkRightSide)` are necessary. Without them, the compiler would understand it as `%%(mkRightSide myvar)`, because function application has a higher priority than the `%%` operator.

---

If I am wrong in guessing your intent, please clarify it, and I'll be happy to amend the answer.

Comment: You guessed my intention correctly. The reason I was avoiding function invocation - is that my current focus is performance. Actually, in the current state of the project, I receive a lambda to invoke on the head tail pair, but I intentionally reduce it by substituting terms with actual head and tail (e.g. I rewrite the lambda tree replacing arg accesses with head or tail respectively). I guess I will just have to resort to constructing that match by hand.